# What is the significance of the strike-through Sow in this Greyjoy sigil?

Tags: discussion

I was just reading this question - [Why did Aegon I Targaryen join the alliance against Volantis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199598/why-did-aegon-i-targaryen-join-the-alliance-against-volantis)

In one of the [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/199602/58193), and its linked image there is a a strike-through "Sow" replaced with the word "Know".

[image: Greyjoy emblem]

What is the context of this?

Comment: It's a terrible joke that the users of the chatroom "The Quill and Tankard" came up with after being repeatedly told that "We don't know" answers were acceptable, and questions requiring that sort of answer are not opinion based, no matter how much the user knows about a specific fandom.

Comment: Jon was made a legitimate Stark and then changed their words to _We do not Snow_.

Comment: I believe this should be on topic per the "fandom information" clause but how far that extends is questionable.

Comment: Tywin sent Tyrion to King's Landing and told him that being a Lannister means, _We do no hoe_.

Comment: Upon learning about Ygritte's relation with Jon, Tormund told her that being a wildling means _We do no crow_. (Ok I'll shut up now :P)

Comment: You guys are off the chain...

Comment: After King Robert was killed by a boar, Cersei took up the title _Widowed by sow_.

Comment: This should be on topic on the main Sci Fi site for a reason similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76125/4918

Comment: I strongly relate to Arya. We do not sew.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a meme created by our resident *A Song of Ice and Fire* expert [@Aegon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54887/aegon). It was created after multiple questions had the answer We Don't Know and as should be obvious it is a play on words on the Greyjoy's words "We Do Not Sow". After the image was used it was taken on by other users, including myself, from the ASOIAF/GoT chatroom [The Quill and Tankard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39179/the-quill-and-tankard).

There is nothing more to it than being a terrible joke, YMMV.

---

For a bit of history the meme started around the 12th of September 2017 as can be seen in the [TQAT transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/39179?m=39959563#39959563). I believe the image was created the same day and used on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/169501/58193) by Aegon.

Comment: On a side note there was a corresponding meme "It is unknown" for a while but it didn't last long.

Comment: What's so terrible about this joke?

Comment: @Dima - Some people have no respect for word play.

Answer (score 4):

It's a joke.  The Greyjoy motto is "We do not sow". The answer to the question is "We do not know".